# How would I return status codes and repsones in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, https, aws-lambda

I am writing a Lambda function which is going to be used to send a test message to an API. If there are errors I will need it to run certain functionality (like notify me with AWS messaging). I would like to have a simple test by status code. for example if i get a 2XX do nothing, if I get a 4XX or 5XX, notify me so i can research issues. In the test environment I am passing the body as an XML string as a value in a JSON object.

example Lambda Test Event

```
{
 "data": "<xml stuff, credentials, etc"
}
```

here is my function

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

const https = require('https');

const options = {
  hostname: 'https://mythingy.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/target',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
};

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);

  res.on('data', d => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.on('error', error => {
  console.error(error);
});

req.write(event.data);
req.end();

};
```

I'm using node 10.x in Lambda, and i am getting a "result succeeded" message from lambda, but no logged response statusCode. I've done it several ways, and have easily pulled statsCodes from Node fetch, ajax, http requests in the past. I know this probably has something to do with Lambda's env anc the promise. Can anyone help me figure out how to log the stats code in Lambda?

Comment: you should look at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see it printed out because your function is `async` and `https.request` uses a callback approach, which will be run asynchronously by the Node.js workers. It turns out that the function will have reached its end before it has a chance to execute the code inside the callback. And yes, you are right, this is due to the way Lambda functions work, because they are short-lived (contexts can be reused, but that's a story for another question), therefore the processes are terminated by the underlying containers. It never happened to you in traditional Node.js applications because they usually run behind a webserver, which is responsible for keeping the process up and running, so callbacks are eventually executed.

You have to either [promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html) `https.request` or use a library which already works with Promises, so you could easily `await` on them. [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) and [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) are good options.

Once you have chosen your library - or have promisified `https.request` - (I'll use `axios` for my example), you can simply `await` on the call, get its results and do whatever you want with it.

```
const res = await axios.post('https://service-you-want-to-connect-to.com', {})
console.log(JSON.stringify(res)) // here you inspect the res object and decide what do to with the status code.
```

Comment: thank you Thales for the descriptive answer/education. question: can i load axios/request in lambda.

Comment: You're more than welcome. I suggest you do that the way you traditionally add dependencies to Node.js applications (either with npm or yarn). So you create a package.json (`npm init`) then you install axios (or request) by running `npm i axios`, zip the code along with your dependencies and upload the zipped file to Lambda. There are tools already that do this for you, but it should be enough to get you off-ground since you are just getting started.

Comment: you rock Thales. thank you much. +2 and answer credit. cheers.